# Rearrange and extract values from a data frame to specific columns in R

Tags: r, dataframe, extract

I have a dataframe df like this

```
> df <- data.frame(type=c("Id","v1","v2","Id","v1","v1","v2","Id","v1","v2","v3"),num=c(1000,200,500,1001,727,50,800,1002,400,365,865))
> df
   type  num
1    Id 1000
2    v1  200
3    v2  500
4    Id 1001
5    v1  727
6    v1   50
7    v2  800
8    Id 1002
9    v1  400
10   v2  365
11   v3  865
```

I need to create another data frame with **Id, v1, v2, v3** as the column names and corresponding values from **df** such that the variable below each id belong to that id and when the same variable repeats it has to be mapped with the same id and if the variable is not present NA has to be given. This is the desired output.

```
    Id  v1  v2  v3
1 1000 200 500  NA
2 1001 727  NA  NA
3 1001  50 800  NA
4 1002 400 365 865
```

I have thought about a method using for loop. But it seems complicated and difficult to structure it. Is there a way without using for loops.

Comment: In case the variable is not present in some cases, how do establish where to put the present value? For instance, for `Id` 1001, we have two `v1` (727 and 50) and one `v2` (800). How do we know that the 800 should be near the `v1` value 50 rather than 727?

Comment: @RicS It is the order which matters and not the value in this case.

Comment: I understand that it's the order, but why 800 in `v2` is near 50 in `v1` and not 727? How do we determine that? For instance, in the solution you accepted, 800 in `v2` is near 727 in `v1` and not 50 (so it's the opposite wrt the output you wrote in your question)

Comment: @RicS For `v1=727` we do not have `v2` and `v3` (if you go with the order) but we have for `v1=50` . that's why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to do it this way

```
   library(tidyverse) 
   df %>% 
      mutate(id = ifelse(type == "Id", num, NA)) %>% 
      fill(id) %>% 
      filter(type != "Id") %>% 
      group_by(id, type) %>% 
      mutate(n = row_number()) %>% 
      pivot_wider(c(id, n), names_from = type, values_from = num) %>% 
      select(-n) %>% 
      ungroup()

# A tibble: 4 x 4
     id    v1    v2    v3
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1  1000   200   500    NA
2  1001   727   800    NA
3  1001    50    NA    NA
4  1002   400   365   865
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. it works! Could you explain the `mutate(n = row_number())` ?

Comment: `row_number()` counts the number of id and type combinations in groups. For example, `id == 10001` and` type == v1` 2 times. Next, using `id` and `n`, the rows of the final table are compiled